# Partial fraction decomposition find the inverse laplace transform

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, laplace-transform

It may sound as a silly question but I want to know clearly why the following partial fraction decomposition is wrong:
Suppose we're solving a ODE using Laplace transform, we find that the Laplace transform of our solution is $F(s)=\frac{1}{s^2(s+1)}$, and that we write it as $F(s)=\frac{A}{s^2}+ \frac{B}{s+1}$, thus finding that the solution is $y(t)=At+Be^{-t}$, which is obviously wrong because we forgot the term $C/s$ in the partial fraction decomposition. The question is, why is it wrong, even if we chose A and B such that $\frac{A}{s^2}+ \frac{B}{s+1}=\frac{1}{s^2(s+1)}$?

Comment: Because there are no such numbers $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The decomposition in partial fractions is rather $A/s^2+B/s+C/(s+1).$

Comment: I invite you to [experiment](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0frg9ibzd3) - there are no two real numbers $A,B$ such that $1/(x^2(x+1))=A/x^2+B/(x+1)$ for all $x$.